# Import .lib file in vs 2019 not working for me

Tags: c++, visual-studio, .lib, import-libraries

i downloaded libvnc library and compiled it.
Now i have vncclient.lib and vncserver.lib.
How can i import in vs 19 ?
I tried this way:

Property - Linker - Input  and put in Additional Dependencies the folder of the .lib file.
After in main i write this.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "vncclient.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "vncserver.lib")
```

if i compile program found the library but if i try some code like

```
#include <rfb.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    rfbScreenInfoPtr server = rfbGetScreen(&argc, argv, 400, 300, 8, 3, 4);
    server->frameBuffer = malloc(400 * 300 * 4);
    rfbInitServer(server);
    rfbRunEventLoop(server, -1, FALSE);
```

the compiler marks me as an error and cannot find the data, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

"Additional dependencies" is for actual .lib files, if you want to add an entire path do it on either the "VC++ Directories" page or in the Linker->General page's "Additional library directries" line.

If you want this library to be available to all projects you build I suggest you add it to the user property page (available through the View->Other Windows->Property Manager menu item), expand the build configurations and select properties from the right click menu of the Microsoft.Cpp..User items.

Comment: I added in Linker yet, vs find the library, but if i import some header of these library or some data type, nothing work

Comment: @CDixon, **"but if i import some header of these library or some data type, nothing work"** Whether you have added the path of the header file to other include directories.(property - >c/c++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories)